# Attach File that was returned in POST call

Tags: hook, webhooks, podio

I have a Podio native webhook that posts to a service we created. That service then returns a PDF. Initially it was attaching the PDF as a file, but it is no longer doing that.

What does the incoming call need to look like to attach that PDF to the Podio item that sent the webhook?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you've used the technique mentioned here - https://developers.podio.com/examples/files ?
The operation would first involve uploading the file and then attaching to an item. Two separate API calls would be required to do so. Later, could you please share the specific error you are facing? Snippets will help too.

Comment: So this can _only_ be done by API? It can't receive a file from the webhook?